# How to extract metadata from NCBI's experiment?

Tags: phylogenetics, sratoolkit, entrez

I want to extract metadata from experiment SRX1596422. I have sratoolkit and Entrex direct but not sure what line of code to use. Here's the link for the experiment: [experiment SRX1596422](https://trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/sra/sra.cgi?view=run_browser&run=SRR390728)

Comment: Hi and welcome. This is certainly a good question, but its not described clearly. If you describe the code you used so far and instead of  singly linking the experiment, just briefly explaining it to us?

Answer (score 3):

You'll want something like:

```
esearch -db sra -query SRX1596422 | efetch -format runinfo
```

This will produce a CSV output to the screen with columns containing the meta information available in SRA:

```
Run,ReleaseDate,LoadDate,spots,bases,spots_with_mates,avgLength,size_MB,AssemblyName,download_path,Experiment,LibraryName,LibraryStrategy,LibrarySelection,LibrarySource,LibraryLayout,InsertSize,InsertDev,Platform,Model,SRAStudy,BioProject,Study_Pubmed_id,ProjectID,Sample,BioSample,SampleType,TaxID,ScientificName,SampleName,g1k_pop_code,source,g1k_analysis_group,Subject_ID,Sex,Disease,Tumor,Affection_Status,Analyte_Type,Histological_Type,Body_Site,CenterName,Submission,dbgap_study_accession,Consent,RunHash,ReadHash
SRR3184375,2016-02-24 00:00:00,2016-02-23 23:14:45,556018223,111203644600,556018223,200,57997,GCA_000001635.1,https://sra-downloadb.be-md.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sos2/sra-pub-run-7/SRR3184375/SRR3184375.1,SRX1596422,,WGS,size fractionation,GENOMIC,PAIRED,0,0,ILLUMINA,Illumina HiSeq 2000,SRP070623,PRJNA312530,,312530,SRS1306521,SAMN04492320,simple,10090,Mus musculus,MCNT_E1,,,,,female,,no,,,,,THE SCRIPPS RESEARCH INSTITUTE,SRA356784,,public,52A6F836C13F2D15755EDE3E52A18D78,240E7130CFE36405818DA5EE2A10E24C
```

The more relevant fields are: Subject_ID, Sex, Disease, Tumor, Affection_Status, Analyte_Type, Histological_Type, Body_Site. Note that not all of these are available for that particular sample.